# Prevent the EF from making two queries

Tags: sql, entity-framework, orm

Is it possible to prevent the EF from making two queries in the following query?

```
var regitriesNames = 
                from registryView in registryViewRepository.GetAll()
                where (
                    from registryReport in registryReportRepository.GetAll()
                    where registryReport.ReportId == reportId
                    select registryReport.RegistryViewId
                ).Contains(registryView.Id)
                select registryView.Name;
```

The query works just fine. The only thing that I would like to avoid is the double use of the `GetAll()`.

So, is it possible to imrove the query somehow?

I have two entities: **RegistryView** and **Report** and I have an entity which represents the many to many relationship between them **RegistryReport**.

Comment: If possible store `GetAll` method result in one `variable` passing the query.

Comment: Why are you calling GetAll()?  And do registryViewRepository and registryReportRepository share a single DbContext instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this one.

> Code

```
var lstdata = registryViewRepository.GetAll();
var regitriesNames = from registryView in lstdata 
                where (
                    from registryReport in lstdata
                    where registryReport.ReportId == reportId
                    select registryReport.RegistryViewId
                ).Contains(registryView.Id)
                select registryView.Name;
```

Comment: Glad this helped , Thanks :)